# Передача list в качестве параметра функции

Tags: c++, функции, list, stl

Я хочу передать неинициализированный `list` в качестве аргумента в функцию `add`, чтобы там его изменить. Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char author[30];
} SONG;

void add( * b)
 {  char a[30];
    cin >> a;  

    
    SONG singer;


    b.push_front(singer); /*тут я хочу получить массив и изменить его, но показывает ошибку*/

    strcpy_s(singer.author, a);

    list<SONG>::iterator it;
    it = b.begin();
    b.insert(++it, singer);

}


int main()
{
    list <SONG> myList;

    cout << "Enter your number :";
    int input;
    cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
    case 1:
        add(list<SONG> &myList);   /*вот тут хочу передать массив по ссылке*/
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error";
        break;
    }

  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте для начала заменить

```
void add( * b)
```

на

```
void add(list <SONG>&b)
```

а вызов

```
add(list<SONG> &myList);
```

на

```
add(myList);
```

Comment: спасибо большое..2 часа. просто 2 часа над такой проблемой. через 7 минут вас отмечу.

Comment: @PashaFromBY, нужно учить язык, а не пытаться методом тыка :) читайте книги по языку.